# Domain class confusion

Tags: grails

I have an app which uses groovy-grails, its a web app.  i have few questions.

1) I have standard ui which on submit gets all the data via webservices. so what should be my domain object look like as i do not have DB table interaction. these objects can be declared under Domian object or they have to be Models/POJO  java classes.

ie say i have employee create screen with , name ,last name, telephone, role. once i hit createemployee service. i get a status either sucess or fails. i will display  them in screen.

can i declare employee as domian class and map each valuein UI?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating it outside the Domain Classes folder.

Comment: If I understand your question completely I agree with creating this Domain object in the src/groovy or src/java package and communicating with it through a controller.

Answer (score 0):

The Grails DomainClass is strongly tied to the database. If you don't need GORM/Hibernate in your project, but use web services instead, you will lose some great features of Grails, but that's ok.

So, I would suggest that you use the DomainClass only to make use of the scaffolding feature in order to get a quick start. After that, you should create a service for accessing your data via web services and use this service instead of the DomainClasses from within you controller.

Take a look at the [data binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) and [command object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) chapter in the Grails reference doc. You have to understand it in order to move your DomainClasses to command objects and get the full benefit of the data binding